# How to map a column to create a new column in spark sql dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apache-spark

In python and pandas, I can create a new column like this:

Using two columns in pandas dataframe to create a dict.

```
 dict1 = dict(zip(data["id"], data["duration"]))
```

Then I can apply this dict to create a new column in a second dataframe.

```
df['id_duration'] = df['id'].map(lambda x: dict1[x] if x in dict1.keys() else -1)
```

How can I create a new column `id_duration` in spark sql dataframe, in case I have a dataframe `data` (having two columns: `id` and `duration`) and a dataframe `df` (having a column `id`)?

Comment: just sudden, i recognize that it may solve by sql join

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a dictionary would be a shame because you would need to collect the entire dataframe `data` onto the driver which will be very bad for performance and could cause an OOM error.

You could simply perform a left outer join between the two dataframes and use `na.fill` to fill empty values with `-1`.

```py
data = spark.createDataFrame([(1, 10), (2, 20), (3, 30)], ['id', 'duration'])
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, 2), (3, 4)], ['id', 'x'])

df\
    .join(data.withColumnRenamed("duration", "id_duration"), ['id'], 'left')\
    .na.fill(-1).show()
```

```
+---+---+-----------+
| id|  x|id_duration|
+---+---+-----------+
|  5|  6|         -1|
|  1|  2|         10|
|  3|  4|         30|
+---+---+-----------+
```

Comment: thanks,its useful.But use Map idea to solve this problem is also appreciated, I think it may be more common.

Comment: I am not sure I understand. You would like a solution that does use a dictionary?

Comment: more solution, more freedom.i just think it is also helpful in some situation.